# Search through two or more ref() in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to search firebase by a 'key' that may exist in two different refs? May be easier to see than explain:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("cars").child(key);
```

However, its possible that I want to look for that key in 'trucks' as well:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref("trucks").child(key);
```

Is there a way to combine the two refs and search for them, sorta like:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref(["cars","trucks"]).child(key);
```

Comment: You could do s.th. like `["cars", "trucks"].forEach(function(value){database.ref(value).child(key);});` Depending on your needs, you might want to switch to `Array#map`.

Comment: Thought about that, but didn't know if Firebase had cleaner solution.

Comment: In your example code, I'm not sure it makes sense to return a single ref from what is effectively a combination of refs.  Each ref is a distinct query and needs to be executed independently.  If you need to join them, you have to write that code yourself.